# difference b/w <script

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between:

1. < script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">< /script>
2. < script type="text/javascript">< /script>
3. < script language="javascript">< /script>

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112482/what-is-the-difference-between-lang-and-type-attributes-in-a-script-tag

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706290/why-write-script-typetext-javascript-when-the-mime-type-is-set-by-the-server/2706345#2706345

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Number 2 is the best you can do for now and for the foreseeable future.**

First, the `language` attribute is deprecated in the [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) and the [draft HTML 5 specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-script-language), and omitted from [XHTML 1.0 Strict](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html), so options 1 and 3 are out.

Second, do you need a type attribute at all? Yes. HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1.0 specifies the `type` attribute as required while HTML5 has it as optional, defaulting to `text/javascript`. Therefore until HTML5 is finalised and widely implemented, you must have the `type` attribute if you want your HTML to be valid, which rules out the simple `<script></script>` (I know this wasn't one of the original options, but it's something that I have seen recommended).

Thirdly, what should go in the type attribute? As noted by Matthew Flaschen, the MIME type `application/javascript` registered in 2006 is intended to replace `text/javascript`. A quote from [the relevant RFC](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt):

> This document thus defines text/javascript and text/ecmascript but marks them as "obsolete".  Use of experimental and unregistered media types, as listed in part above, is discouraged.  The media types,
>
> ```
>   * application/javascript
>   * application/ecmascript
> ```
>
> which are also defined in this document, are intended for common use and should be used instead.

However, IE (up to and including version 8) doesn't execute script inside a `<script>` element with a `type` attribute of either `application/javascript` or `application/ecmascript`, so these are both unusable for the foreseeable future and we're stuck with `text/javascript`.

Answer (score 7):

All of them are technically deprecated, but the second annoys people least. :)

Both language (see W3C [XHTML 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/abstract_modules.html#s_legacymodule)) and text/javascript are deprecated (see [MIME registry for text](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/)).  The [recommended](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/) mime type is application/javascript, but this is not backwards-compatible.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

HTML 4.01 / XHTML 1.0 Transitional with deprecated language attribute

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

HTML 4.01 / XHTML 1.0 Strict (or Transitional without deprecated language attribute)

```
<script language="javascript"></script>
```

HTML 3.2