# <script type="text/javascript"> Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined

Tags: javascript

Is it possible that where the `"language"` of the script is not explicitly defined, the JavaScript will not be executed?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

This piece of JavaScript which is embedded onto the JSP / HTML page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MIME-Type of the file is set by the server. For JS files a MIME-Type of `text/javascript` should be returned. It's not doing this here, that's why you get the notice.

The `language` property in `<script>` is deprecated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

is correct.

Also see: [What is the difference between "lang" and "type" attributes in a script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112482/what-is-the-difference-between-lang-and-type-attributes-in-a-script-tag)

The MIME-type is a header the server sends along with any file that is requested. The client is free to ignore it of course. Usually if your file is a *.js file your webserver will select the right MIME-type for you, if your file is a .jsp script that returns a JavaScripts file then you will likely need to set the MIME-type header yourself, this is fairly trivial in most languages, I wouldn't know how to do it in JSP but in PHP it's: header("MIME-Type: text/javascript"); anywhere before you start echo'ing the actual content.

Comment: Hi Campen, can you please share how you arrived at the concolusion that the MIME-type is set by the server? I find this the closest lead. Is there anyway in which we can influence this? Some of my javascripts are getting ignored (e.g. not executed) because of this.

Comment: The MIME-type is a header the server sends along with any file that is requested. The client is free to ignore it of course. Usually if your file is a *.js file your webserver will select the right MIME-type for you, if your file is a .jsp script that _returns_ a JavaScripts file then you will likely need to set the MIME-type header yourself, this is fairly trivial in most languages, I wouldn't know how to do it in JSP but in PHP it's: `header("MIME-Type: text/javascript");` anywhere before you start echo'ing the actual content.

Answer (score 1):

The language attribute of the script tag is virtually universally depreciated; you no longer require it.

In addition, HTML5 does not require the type attribute if it's Javascript, but you may want to keep it for older browsers.

http://css-tricks.com/15276-the-script-tag/

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't matter at all, for any reason. All it's saying is that it was downloaded as just a page, but the browser interpreted it as JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message "Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined", doesn't seems like javascript problem. Please use some browser extension tool to monitor all the responses, check if any special resource or file returned from server.