# jQuery Function "undefined" according to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-progressbar

This may be a pretty simple question about jQuery UI and Javascript, but I am still feeling my way through these syntax's.  I am trying to update a jQuery progress bar whenever my C# (ASP.NET) program reaches a certain point in different functions.  Am I doing this correctly?  I can see the empty progress bar on my page, but I cannot get it to update its progress.

Here are my scripts:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });
  });

function updateProgress(number) {
        if (number < 100) {
            $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", number);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here are some more of my script references:

```
 <link href="Styles/tomcat.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<link href="Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.progressbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Scripts/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And here is where I try to use the updateProgress() function via a C# function.  I am trying to send "10%" to the progress bar but my debugger errors out and says that updateProgress() is not defined.

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='javascript'>UpdateProgress(10);</script>", false);
```

EDIT: I added the following boolean to bypass the page refreshing and refreshing my progress bar.

```
 var runOnce = new Boolean;
runOnce = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(!runOnce)
    {
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });
        runOnce = true;
    }
});
```

I don't think it is working though.  It still clears and sets it back to zero every page load.

Answer (score 5):

javascript is case sensitive. either change your function declaration to `UpdateProgress` or change your injection to `updateProgress`.

also i believe you should including `type="text/javascript"` on your script tag - language is a deprecated attribute. related: [What is the difference between "lang" and "type" attributes in a script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112482/what-is-the-difference-between-lang-and-type-attributes-in-a-script-tag)

Edit: to handle the progress getting overwritten:

```
var progressAlreadySet;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar(); // initialize

    if (!progressAlreadySet) {
        $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", 0);
    }
});

var updateProgress = function (number) {
    if (number < 100) {
        progressAlreadySet = true;
        $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", number);
    }
};
```

Comment: Okay, I changed it, and I no longer receive that error, but it still isn't performing the update on the progress bar.

Comment: Wait, I just thought of something.  Do you think it is performing the update, but because I am calling the update behind an ASP button click it is refreshing the page and thus setting the progress bar back to 0?

Comment: @se_brandon your `document.ready` is probably executing after your startup script and setting the progress back to 0.

Comment: How do I go about changing/avoiding that?

Comment: @se_brandon the first thing that comes to mind would be a flag that your injection sets and the document.ready does nothing if the flag is set. essentially, a "page has been posted back" flag on the client.

Comment: I added this boolean code segment above, something like that?

Comment: That causes the progressbar to not render on the page load.  It exists on the first page load and after the button is pushed, it disappears.

Comment: @se_brandon oh i see. you are initializing it in the document.ready and passing a settings object, where you are only setting an option from `updateProgress`. see my edit :P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13853/discussion-between-se-brandon-and-jbabey)

Comment: @se_brandon blocked by my corporate firewall, sorry :P

Comment: Ah, okay, well that edit you performed above just caused the code to reinitialize the progressbar.  And where would it store the value of number between page loads?

Comment: @se_brandon sorry, that should have been `0` not `number`, copy and pasted it.

Comment: Doesn't var progressAlreadySet get reinitialized whenever the script runs on page load again?