# Case, when "document.ready" obstruct

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have php file, in this file I have this code:

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        $(document).ready( function () {
            var myvar = <?php   echo json_encode($myvar);   ?> ;
        });
    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="costum.js">  </script>
```

and in costum.js file I have code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    alert(myvar );
});
```

this not working, error consol returns "myvar  is undefined"

if in php file I write this (that is, without "document.ready")

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
     var myvar = <?php   echo json_encode($myvar);   ?> ;
 </script>
```

in costum.js file, code alredy is working. Please tell why this happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with

```
<script>
    var myvar;
    $(document).ready( function () {
        myvar = <?php   echo json_encode($myvar);   ?> ;
    });
</script>
```

your variable has to be declared as global (or in other words, in the outer scope) to be viewed from both `document.ready` functions.

As a side note `language` attribute is not necessary. Even `type` is not necessary (if you're using `html5` doctype)

Comment: Thanks, understood and thanks for side "language attribute" information.
 Mr. Bergi and Mr.  xdazz,  You also Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `myvar` is in the local scope of the ready-function. Move the `var` declaration outside to make it global and available to the other script.

However, as you just assign to a variable, you won't need to wait for DOMready anyway. Just use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myvar = <?php echo json_encode($myvar); ?>;
</script>
```

BTW, the `language` attribute [is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/112515/1048572).

Answer (score 1):

local variable inside the function is only visible in the function scope.

when you declare variable in the global scope, then it is the global variable.

You could expose it to global scope by:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
      var myvar = <?php   echo json_encode($myvar);   ?>;
      window['myvar'] = myvar;
 });
```