# Using jquery variable outside of $(document).ready

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery and I have 2 different js files.

**file_1.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var A = 'varA';
});
```

**file_2.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(A); // will get an A is undefined because of this closure thing
});
```

Is there any way to access one variable from one file from another file?
I need all the code to be inside $(document).ready(...)

One solution, I used is to make variable global (without using var A)
Is there anything better?

Comment: Someone just asked right now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248366/case-when-document-ready-obstruct/12248422#12248400

Comment: Any global variable is technically a property of the `window` object. Similarly, you can store variables in `.data()` on any appropriate DOM object if you really need to.

Comment: You could also use the `document` namespace and do `this.A` inside the ready function, like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/WpyUf/9/)...

Answer (score 5):

Create your own namespace:

```
var my = {};

...

 $(document).ready(function(){
     my.A = 'A';
 }

 ...

 $(documet).ready(function() {
     console.log(my.A);
 }
```

This way, you only have one global variable **my** that acts as a namespace for all your "global" objects/functions

Answer (score 0):

Var A is defined in the function and its lifespan is restricted to the execution of the function. You need to make it global, that is why global vars exist in the first place.