# Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I receive this error in Google Chrome using this script in the HEADER.

Could you help me out to understand what is wrong?

```
**Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL**



 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#DateTimeStart).datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: The code highlighting should already tell you what's wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start you should specify the type of your script blocks e.g.

```
<script type='text/javascript'></script>
```

But the actual problem is that you don't have a second apostrophe after DateTimeStart e.g.

```
$('#DateTimeStart').datetimepicker();
```

EDIT: Removed my bad advice :)

Comment: Not quite the good advice... The `language` attribute is [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/112515/255756).

Comment: Ooh do you know I didn't even think about that. Will edit.

Answer (score 2):

You have missing ending quote

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#DateTimeStart').datetimepicker();
        });
```